React Native issue with push notifications event handler when the app is in Background State
I've got the following issue with push notifications in my android device when the app is in Background State. My app has been built with React Native and I'm using @react-native-firebase/messaging library in order to handle push notifications from FCM. In my entry point of the application (index.js) I've got the following code:
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import React from 'react';
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';
import { name as appName } from './app.json';

messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async (remoteMessage) => {
    console.log('Background Handler: ', remoteMessage);
});

function HeadlessCheck({ isHeadless, notificationWithLink }) {
    if (isHeadless) {
        return null;
    }

    return <App notificationWithLink={notificationWithLink} />;
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => HeadlessCheck);

When a push notification arrives with the app in Quit State, setBackgroundMessageHandler is fired and I can see the log of remoteMessage, but when my application is in Background State, that handler isn't fired.
In both cases, the notification is displayed by the system, but I'm not able to handle the received remoteMessage. I need to handle the remoteMessage with the purpose to send to a database information about the push notification when the app is in Background State. The body of my request to FCM is the following:
{                  
       "message":  {        
            "android":{
                "priority":"high"
            },
            "apns":{
                "headers":{
                    "apns-priority":"5"
                }
            },
            "token": "BSDJAJSDASNLDKAKLSDLKVDNFODSKFOPKSDFSFIOJIOEOIGJEOIRGJIOSDOIFJIADSOJFOIA",        
            "notification": {
                "title": "Notification title",
                "body": "Notification description"
            },
            "data": {            
                "phone_number": "1234567890",
                "deep_link": "myDeeplink"
            }
       } 
}

I'm not sure what the problem is. Hope you can help me.
I tried to implement messaging().onMessage(() => {}) handler inside of my index.js file, but it didn't work.
